# Issues with update action using acts_as_votable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, voting-system

I'm currently getting the votes to hit the database but I'm now having issues getting the update action to work in my controller. The votes don't record with the update action but do without out it. However, I then get a missing template error for Pits#update. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Terminal Error

```
Started PUT "/pits/3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-21 11:38:25 -0500
Processing by PitsController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 4  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Pit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "pits".* FROM "pits"  WHERE "pits"."user_id" = ? AND "pits"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 4], ["id", 3]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 64ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Pit with 'id'=3 [WHERE "pits"."user_id" = ?]):
  app/controllers/pits_controller.rb:37:in `update'
```

I currently have

Pits Controller

class PitsController < ApplicationController

```
def new
  @pit = Pit.new
end

def index
  @pit = Pit.all
  @user = User.find_by(params[:id])
  @pits = Pit.paginate(:page => params[:page]).order('created_at ASC').group_by { |pit| pit.created_at.strftime("%B %Y") }
end




def create
  @user = current_user
  @pit = current_user.pits.create(pit_params)
    if @pit.save
      redirect_to @pit
    else
      render 'new'
    end
end



def show
  @pit = Pit.find(params[:id])
end

def edit
end

def update
   @user = current_user
   @pit = current_user.pits.find(params[:id])
   if @pit.update_attributes(pit_params)
      redirect_to @pit
end
end

private

def pit_params
    params.require(:pit).permit(:topic, :summary, :image, :video_url, :author, :user_id)
end

end
```

Comments Controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController


 def create
  @pit= Pit.find(params[:pit_id])
  @comment = @pit.comments.build(comments_params)
  @comment.user = current_user
  @comment.save

  redirect_to pit_path(@pit)
end

  def destroy
    @pit = Pit.find(params[:pit_id])
    @comment = @pit.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to pit_path(@pit)
end

def upvote
  @pit = Pit.find(params[:pit_id])
  @comment = @pit.comments.find(params[:comment_id])
  @comment.upvote_by current_user
  redirect_to pit_path(@pit)
end

def downvote
  @pit = Pit.find(params[:pit_id])
  @comment = @pit.comments.find(params[:comment_id])
  @comment.downvote_from current_user
  redirect_to pit_path(@pit)
end

def update
end




def show  
end

  private

def comments_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :user_id, :votable, :voter, :vote_scope)
end

end
```

_comment.html.erb

```
  <div class = "well">
    <p>
    <strong>Comment:</strong>
    <%= comment.body %>
    <p>posted by: <%= comment.user.name %></p>
       <%= link_to "Like", pit_comment_like_path(@pit, comment), method: :put , :remote => true %>
       <%= link_to "Dislike", pit_comment_dislike_path(@pit, comment), method: :put, :remote => true %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%if comment.user == current_user %>

     <%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [@pit, comment],
                 method: :delete,
                 data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    <% end %>             
  </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `current_user` (4) is the one who created the pit with id (3)?  Try `Pit.find(3).user_id` in the console.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It wasn't the same user. But I want anyone to be able to vote on any comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about everything you have going on here, but I suspect the error has to do with use `current_user` to find the `pit`. If the current_user is not the `user_id` for the pit, it won't find any pit (exactly your error).

Try adjusting to this and it should be able to find the pit propperly.

```
def update
   @pit = Pit.find(pit_params[:id])
   if @pit.update_attributes(pit_params)
      redirect_to @pit
end
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be updating the database, however I'm getting some type of redirect error in my terminal. Its showing

"Started PUT "/pits/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-22 11:12:17 -0500
Processing by PitsController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 1ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: pit):
  app/controllers/pits_controller.rb:45:in `pit_params'
  app/controllers/pits_controller.rb:36:in `update'"

Comment: Try removing the `method: put` and `remote: true` on the `link_to`

Comment: Just did it tehfailsafe and it worked. Thanks. Both responses here helped and I appreciate it very much.

Comment: What was the "remote" doing? I'd be curious to know how that was screwing it up.

Comment: `remote: true` causes the link to execute as async javascript, if that's not what you intend to do it can cause errors if you don't respond to it.

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html